# What does the Abkürzung (abbreviation) SV mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviation

What does *SV* mean within the following Context:

> Eintritt: VVK € 10,90 / TK € 12,- / inkl. Gebühren / SV.

Comment: Could you please give even more context?

Comment: My guess is that the "V" in "SV" stands for `Versicherung`, so perhaps `Sportversicherung`? (Assuming this is a sports event.)

Comment: I have no clue, but I found it also for concerts (I googled the sentence)

Comment: Could you link to the original resource, Adli? It just could mean "Sportverein" and you cut off the name of the sports club by accident.

Comment: Alle bisherigen Ideen sind so schlecht, dass mir wahrscheinlicher dünkt, es könne sich um einen Schreibfehler handeln, und es könnte "VS" als immernoch seltsame Abkürzung für Versand gemeint sein. Gut finde ich die Erklärung nicht, aber "Vergnügungssteuer" wäre auch umgekehrt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich schließé den Schreibfehler aus, da es zu viele Quellen gibt, die es verwenden.

Comment: @userunknown Versand wird es auch nicht sein, dann wäre es kein / sondern schlichtweg ein *und*. SV hat keinen Bezug auf die Gebühren!

Comment: @Em1: Wo sind diese Quellen?

Comment: @userunknown Zweites Suchergebnis meiner Google Suche schickt mich [hier hin](http://www.mousonturm.de/archiv/). Dort allein findest du es mehrmals!

Comment: Das war die Stelle, die ich auch gefunden hatte, und die zähle ich nur einfach - es könnte ein systematischer Fehler einer Person/Software sein.

Comment: what kind of event was the ticket for?

Comment: Ich habe dafür im I-Net eine einzige FSt. in FFM aufgetan, wo die Abkz. allerdings mehrfach vorkommt. Für mich keine gängige Abkz, sondern schlicht falsch.

Answer (score 7):

**Service und Versand**.  It looks like only some Jazz outfit in Frankfurt used this construction in [a couple of their 2012 listings](http://www.jazz-frankfurt.de/?m=201207&cat=10).  It might be a mistake.

Normally you'd see these charges (especially *Versand* = mailing) with *zzgl.* (*zuzüglich*, meaning in addition) in front of them as they are extra costs added on.  The way they've written it above, it sounds like they are included -- which is most unusual.

Answer (score 6):

Ich habe es bereits als Abkürzung für "Steuern und Versicherungen" bei einem Konzertveranstalter gesehen (ich konnte die Abkürzung auch nicht entschlüsseln, dort stand es aber in den AGBs aufgeschlüsselt).

Leider ist es auch nur eine Deutung, könnte in dem genannten Kontext allerdings passen.

Bzw. kann es natürlich auch für "Sozialversicherung" stehen.

---

I've seen it used for "Steuern und Versicherungen" (taxes and insurances) (was used and explained in the terms and conditions on a ticket I had some time ago).

Unfortunately there is not a clear explanation.

Also possible is "Sozialversicherung" (social insurance).

Comment: Steuern u. Versicherungen wären aber 2 Worte. Sozialversicherung befremdet mich vollends.

Comment: @user unknown: ich finde es ohnehin sehr befremdlich, Abkürzungen zu verwenden, die sich eindeutig selbst erklären.

Comment: Bis jetzt für mich die beste Vermutung (!). Zu dem Thema zwei Worte: Da müssten dann zwei Punkte stehen, oder: "S.V."
Ich denke mal, dass diese Regel nicht so vielen Leuten bewusst ist, das könnte also ein Fehler sein.

Comment: @0x6d64 dann müssten beim VVK auch Punkte sein.

Comment: @blindfold: Wieso? Vorverkauf ist ein Wort - es müsste dann aber Vvk. lauten.

Answer (score -2):

could mean ["Schulvorstellung"](http://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=inkl%20/sv&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&hs=wtL&rls=de&channel=suggest&q=vvk%20TK%20SV%20abk%C3%BCrzung&oq=vvk%20TK%20SV%20abk%C3%BCrzung&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...3573l5974l0l6261l10l10l0l0l0l0l304l1072l0j2j2j1l5l0.llsin.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e5abca528c455c6d&biw=1333&bih=656) ...

Comment: Really? *inklusive Gebühren/Schulvorstellung*. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: yeah true.. I look at the "this" link again, and it doesn't make much sense so I took it out... but SV can theoretically mean Schulvorstellung as the first link proves.

Comment: @musiKk Der Slash ist ein Trennstrich, der die einzelnen Aufzählungen trennt. Schulvorstellung ist zwar unwahrscheinlich, dennoch möglich, da es keinen Bezug auf die Gebühren hat, somit ist die Frage über Sinn oder Unsinn irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

It might stand for *Studenten/Schüler Vorteil*; it would mean that students can get a reduction on the price.

Comment: I don't think so, because 1. it would be placed after TK, 2. with notice, that passport is necessary and 3. there would be a price given.